# How can I load a class based view by slug?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I've created a view to edit a user:

```
class UsersEditView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
    success_url = reverse('user-list')
```

which edits this model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = EmailField(unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='email', max_length=10, unique=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

I defined the url this way:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', UsersListView.as_view(), name='user-list'),
    path('new/', UsersCreateView.as_view(), name='user-new'),
    path('edit/<str:slug>/', UsersEditView.as_view(), name='user-edit')
]
```

and I test it like this:

```
class EditUserTest(AbstractTest):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        user = User(email='email@provider', first_name='Test', last_name='User', slug='slug', password='qqq')
        user.save()

    def test_edit_user(self):
        response = EditUserTest.client.get(reverse('user-edit', args=('slug', )))
```

except response is always 404:

```
ipdb> response.status_code
404
```

So, what am I missing?

This is for Django 2.0.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that User creation in `setUpClass`. It should go in `setUp`, as it needs to be run once per test case. And you should use `self.client` in the test method itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass

`kwargs={'slug': 'slug'}` instead of `args=('slug', )`

Comment: Still 404: response = EditUserTest.client.get(reverse('user-edit', kwargs={'slug': 'slug'}))